# Why does the "-or" flag to GNU find cause my expression to evaluate in an unexpected way?

Tags: find

The following works as expected:

```
[pitserver ~]% sudo find /home/pitserver/operator -uid 11 -exec ls -nld {} +
drwxr-xr-x 2 11 28 4096 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator
-rw------- 1 11 28   32 Oct  3  2005 /home/pitserver/operator/.amandahosts
-rw------- 1 11 28  700 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.viminfo
-rw------- 1 11 28   65 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.Xauthority
```

I would expect the following to list every file, but instead it lists every file *except* `.amandahosts`:

```
[pitserver ~]% sudo find /home/pitserver/operator -name '.amandahosts' -or -uid 11 -exec ls -nld {} +        
drwxr-xr-x 2 11 28 4096 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator
-rw------- 1 11 28  700 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.viminfo
-rw------- 1 11 28   65 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.Xauthority
```

**Why is this the case?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find), juxtaposition (which is an implied "and" operator) takes precendence over the `-or` operator, so one might expect the arguments to be evaluated like so:

( `-name '.amandahosts' -or -uid 11` ) and ( `-exec ls -ld {} +` )

In fact, if I add the parens to the find command, it works as expected:

```
[pitserver ~]% sudo find /home/pitserver/operator '(' -name '.amandahosts' -or -uid 11 ')' -exec ls -nld {} +
drwxr-xr-x 2 11 28 4096 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator
-rw------- 1 11 28   32 Oct  3  2005 /home/pitserver/operator/.amandahosts
-rw------- 1 11 28  700 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.viminfo
-rw------- 1 11 28   65 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.Xauthority
```

However, find actually interprets the arguments like this:

( `-name '.amandahosts'` ) or ( `-uid 11 -exec ls -ld {} +` )

As you can see here:

```
[pitserver ~]% sudo find /home/pitserver/operator -name '.amandahosts' -or '(' -uid 11 -exec ls -nld {} + ')'
drwxr-xr-x 2 11 28 4096 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator
-rw------- 1 11 28  700 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.viminfo
-rw------- 1 11 28   65 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.Xauthority
```

What's happening here is that the "or" is short-circuiting.  The second part of the '-or' (`-uid 11 -exec ls -ld {} +`) is evaluated **only if** the first part (`-name '.amandahosts'`) evaluates to **false**.  So find will only run `-exec ...` if the file is not named `'.amandahosts'`.  One way to see how this works is to observe that the following succeeds:

```
[pitserver ~]% sudo find /home/pitserver/operator -name '.amandahosts' -exec ls -nld {} + -or -uid 11 -exec ls -nld {} +
-rw------- 1 11 28 32 Oct  3  2005 /home/pitserver/operator/.amandahosts
drwxr-xr-x 2 11 28 4096 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator
-rw------- 1 11 28  700 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.viminfo
-rw------- 1 11 28   65 Jan 30  2006 /home/pitserver/operator/.Xauthority
```

The best way to solve this problem seems to be to always use parens when using an "or" operator, as this gives exactly the desired behavior:

`'(' -name '.amandahosts' -or -uid 11 ')' -exec ls -nld {} +`

Comment: Apparently, you don't understand precedence.  Higher precedence means "binds tighter".  The manpage says `-and` has higher precedence than `-or`, so "A -or B -and C" means "A -or (B -and C)".